# get name from one table with match id in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to solve this problem:

I have two tables

1st table :

register

```
=====================================================
ID       NAME    Mailid      Subject_id    username..password etc
-----------------------------------------------------
34       John     xx          1             xxx
17       Mike    xxx          2             xxx
5        Alan    xxx          4             xxx
10       Dave    xxxx         3             xxxx
```

2nd table

```
subject_id      subject       
  1              maths    
  2              science
  3             chemistry
  4              physics
```

and I want to get result like this

```
ID       NAME    Mailid      Subjectname    username..password etc
-----------------------------------------------------
34       John     xx           maths              xxx
17       Mike    xxx          science             xxx
5        Alan    xxx          physics            xxx
10       Dave    xxxx         chemistry          xxxx
```

Instead of subject id, I want subject name.

Comment: I like better your `Subject_id` using INT than polluting your database with unnecessary repetitive strings. Should not be hard than to create an additional Inno-DB relational table `subjects` with foreign-keys pointing to those ID values and with an additional `name` column for *maths, science...* etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table1` = your first table containing user detail.

`table2` = your second table containing subject detail.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table1.mailid, table2.subjectname, table1.username, table1.password, ......
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.subject_id = table2.subjectname
GROUP BY table1.id
```